# Laptop stops booting if wireless mouse receiver attached

Tags: boot, usb, lenovo-laptop, logitech-mouse

I have a wireless Logitech MX mouse with a Nano receiver. Every time I reboot my laptop, my computer stops at the ThinkVantage screen and doesn't proceed further.

I have to remove the USB Nano receiver - the computer will then boot without any problems. Any ideas why this is happening?

In my BIOS settings I have disabled USB boot but it had no effect.

Comment: Can you just remove the USB device at that point, or do you have to remove it, and restart the entire laptop to continue booting?

Comment: i have to turn off and then start again

Answer (score 2):

On [this](http://forum.soft32.com/windows/Boot-Problem-USB-ftopict342285.html) forum, they suggest going into the BIOS (comment if you need instructions on that, and I'll add them), and then find an option that contains "legacy usb", and disable it.