# Won't boot with Logitech "unifying receiver" plugged in (remove it, boots fine)

Tags: boot, logitech-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop stops booting if wireless mouse receiver attached](https://superuser.com/questions/279330/laptop-stops-booting-if-wireless-mouse-receiver-attached)

When trying to boot, computer won't get past first screen.

If I remove the Logitech Unifying Receiver from the USB port, the computer boots with no problem. I can then re-insert the receiver, and the wireless mouse (Logitech M510) works great from that point forward.

Comment: I had a mouse with that technology and laptop booted without problems. What Do You mean "...computer won't get past first srceen" does it hangs permanently on bios checking?
Did You tried to put it in another usb port ?

Answer (score 2):

You might try looking for a 'enable legacy usb' type option in the bios.  Toggle its value.

If you don't have something like that, I'm at a loss, as I don't really see how the HID protocols from the receiver could affect a boot, unless some strange boot code is seeing the dongle as some sort of boot device.    weird.

Answer (score -1):

You might try going into BIOS and changing your boot order so that USB comes after your HDD. I wouldn't think that a unifying receiver would register as a bootable device, but then again I have seen people's computers try to boot from iPods that weren't in "disk mode" before...

Comment: solution "good" almost as removing the dongle...

Comment: Please explain. Not sure why this isn't at least a good place to start?