# Windows 10 will not boot unless I unplug wireless Logitech Mouse USB receiver

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, mouse, windows-update

yesterday, I updated my Windows 10 x64 Build 1607 installation, and after the updates were finished, I decided to manually reboot. That took me to a black screen with a set of white circles rotating at the lower end of the screen.

This process didn't stop, so after 10 minutes or so I began googling on another computer, finding a possible solution: unplug any USB receivers, and when I tried this with the USB receiver of my Logitech M510 mouse, Windows booted immediately to my desktop. Unbelievable, but I would like to understand why this happens at all, especially regarding the fact that users reported similar behaviours back in 2015 already, so one would assume that Microsoft must have fixed this issue.

Can anybody explain what exactly happens here after the update that causes this very strange behaviour?

Edit: just to clarify: this happened only once after the update, never again after a normal start. I just wanted to nknow why the update process can cause such a behaviour

Comment: Go to the BIOS and try  turn off boot from USB fdd/hdd , next system should start normal.

Comment: Try the answer here http://superuser.com/questions/279330/laptop-stops-booting-if-wireless-mouse-receiver-attached. Also if its in a usb 3 slot try it on a usb 2; or vice versa (different controller)

Comment: Have you tested the suggested solutions? Did you find something that worked?

Answer (score 1):

On my system (Dell XPS 8700), the problem was fixed by moving the unifying receiver from a USB 3.0 port to a USB 2.0 port.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. After 2-months of problem solving, including getting the bios updated at computer shop, found out it was the Logitech Dongle. Unplugged it from USB 3.0 port to USB 2.0 port and worked fine.

It seems with USB 3.0 it will recognize the dongle as a drive, and try to boot from it when turning the computer on. But not on USB 2.0.

I don't want to disable USB on boot, as we do not have a hard-wired keyboard.