# Logitech M510 mouse makes Windows 10 freeze after Patchday until USB Receiver is removed

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, freeze, windows-update

ever since the latest three monthly Windows-10 patchdays (i.e. beginning sometime in June or July 2016 or so), I am experiencing the following problem with every monthly Win10-update:

- Updates are being installed, then Windows reboots
- after reboot, a black kscreen appears, with a spinning circles-whatever animated icon at the lower center screen
- this animation lasts for hours, unless you remove the USB receiver of the Logitech MX510 mouse. Then Windows boots immediately. If not, that loop lasts forever. Took me a while to actually figure out that the mouse was causing this Windows problem...
- Windows then boots normally everytime, even with the mouse USB receiver connected. No problems during everyday work, restarts also work flawlessly.
- However, when the next patchday arrives a month later, the problem reoccurs after installing updates, and I have to shortly remove the usb receiver again.

Any idea what is happening here? How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: Same here, for me it started happening around the time 10.1 was released. An [old answer here](http://superuser.com/q/279330/371) suggests checking the BIOS settings for "legacy usb support", still haven't tried that.